# spring stateful session bean

Tags: spring, session, ejb, stateful

As programmers are using SPRING api instead of EJB to develop applications, I stumbled upon how to implement "STATEFUL SESSION BEANS of EJB" in SPRING.

Is it possible to implement stateful session beans completely in spring (without any EJB) , if so, I would appreciate any links to the tutorial.

Thanks,
Sri

Answer (score 0):

Use the session scope (`@Scope( value = "session", proxyMode = ScopedProxyMode.TARGET_CLASS )`). But if you only need to store some user input, then one use usually the HttpSession (@SessionAttributes)

You can have a look at this tutorial: [Session-scoped beans in Spring](http://springinpractice.com/2008/05/08/session-scoped-beans-in-spring) - It uses XML to define the scope of the session scoped bean (`cart`), but I think it anyway a good point to start.

- [Spring Reference Chapter 3.5.4.3 Session scope](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/beans.html#beans-factory-scopes-session)
- [Spring Reference Chapter 15.3.2.9 Specifying attributes to store in a session with @SessionAttributes](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html#mvc-ann-sessionattrib)